# Facebook OAuth: Callback URI gives me an HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, oauth

So I am pretty much using the default MVC-template that includes OAuth authentication with facebook. But after authenticating I am getting an `HTTP ERROR 500`.

I am using OAuth Version 4.0. My ConfigureAuth looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    // Local Login Cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3),
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Facebook
    var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AppId = "[MY APP ID]",
        AppSecret = "[MY APP SECRET]",
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
    };

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
}
```

In my facebook app I have added `https://localhost:44365/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` to my valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I have searched for an answer but couldnt find anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 2018 Strict mode is enabled by default.
Add the following callback URIs in your facebook App settings:

> http://localhost:44365/
>
> http://localhost:44365/ExternalLoginCallback
>
> http://localhost:44365/signin-facebook

Comment: I am having a problem with .netcore. When I try to login through facebook, it goes to facebook, ask for permission and come back to the URL like 'www.example.com/signin-facebook?code=xxx&state=xxx'. And on this page, it throws 500 error; this error happend after I published my app and made the facebook app LIVE.

Further, 'https://www.example.com/signin-facebook' does exist in my OAuth Valid redirect URI in facebook app. Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. It works for localhost but fails when I deploy it.